# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Getting an error as below, what should I do to resolve this error.

```
1617299449.374 31040-31040 E/ncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in app
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class layout
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class layout
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.layout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/xxx==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/xxx==/lib/arm64, /data/app/xxx==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
```

DiscFragment.java :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    container.removeAllViews();
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(getFragmentLayout(), container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

    return rootView;
}

  @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        xView = ViewModelProviders.of(this, xViewModelFactory).get(ViewModel.class);
        xView.getViewModelState().observe(getActivity(), this);
    }
```

disc.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <data>
            <variable
                name="discover"
                type="xx.ViewModel" />
        </data>
    
        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/disc_dis"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_sheet_peek_height"
                android:background="@{discover.isEnabled ? @drawable/corner_dark : @drawable/corner_light}"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/to"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/to"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/light_gray_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/pd"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
    
                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/disys"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        tools:listitem="@layout/item_disy_item" />
    
                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/disc"
                        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/progress_bar"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/progress_bar"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_width"
                        android:indeterminate="true"
                        android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/background_color"
                        android:progressTint="@color/progressbar_color"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.474"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.326" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/state_message"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/pd6"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingStart="@dimen/element_margin"
                        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/element_margin"
                        android:text="@string/progress_message"
                        android:textColor="@{discover.isEnabled ? @color/text_white : @color/text_black_color}"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/size"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/disc" />
    
                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:id="@+id/btn_error_action"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/pd12"
                        android:background="@color/action_btn_background"
                        android:padding="@dimen/action_btn_padding"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/state_message"
                        tools:text="@string/expo_turn_bluetooth_on_label" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </layout>


    <color name="text_white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="text_black_color">#272626</color>

corner_dark.xml : 

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <corners android:topLeftRadius="16dp"
            android:topRightRadius="16dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/darktheme"></solid>
        <size android:height="48dp"/>
        <padding android:left="4dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="4dp" android:bottom="4dp" />
    </shape>


corner_light.xml : 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <corners android:topLeftRadius="12dp"
            android:topRightRadius="12dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/white"></solid>
        <size android:height="48dp"/>
        <padding android:left="4dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="4dp" android:bottom="4dp" />
    </shape>
```

Comment: Did you enable data binding in your module's `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Yes .     dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

Comment: OK, then, why are you using `inflate()` on a `LayoutInflater`? Shouldn't you be using the generated binding class, both to inflate the layout and to replace ButterKnife?

Comment: What's `getFragmentLayout()`?

Comment: @Override
    protected int getFragmentLayout() {
        return R.layout.disc;
    }

Comment: @CommonsWare : Thanks. I added the bindings and is getting the error, that the binding does not exist